# How to dynamically add properties to an object in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, discord.js

I have an object in which I want to be able to dynamically add at least one property.
The amount of properties depends on the items inside of an array that I have.
Here's the object I'm referencing:

```js
const helpEmbedMsg = new global.Discord.MessageEmbed()
                // Display a different (random) color every time the command is used.
                .setColor("RANDOM")
                .setTitle("Help")
                .setAuthor("Beatrice~")
                .setDescription("A full list of the commands available to you..")
                .addFields(
                    { name: `The current __prefix__ for this server is:   \`${prefix}\``, value: "\u200B" },
                )
                .addField(" Here's a list of all my commands:", "\u200B", false)

                .addField("\u200B", "\u200B", false)
                .addField(`Type \`${prefix}help <command>\` to learn more about a command and it's usage!   `, `Example: \`${prefix}help ping\``, false)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter(`Command triggered in ${message.channel.guild}`);
```

So, basically, if the length of the array is 4, I want to add the following:

```js
.addField(array[i], "text here", true)
```

four times, but in a specific place in the object (the order counts), right below this line:

```js
.addField(" Here's a list of all my commands:", "\u200B", false)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, just break up the code into two chains with a `for` loop between them:

```
const helpEmbedMsg = new global.Discord.MessageEmbed();

helpEmbedMsg.setColor("RANDOM")
    .setTitle("Help")
    .setAuthor("Beatrice~")
    .setDescription("A full list of the commands available to you..")
    .addFields(
        { name: `The current __prefix__ for this server is:   \`${prefix}\``, value: "\u200B" },
    )
    .addField(" Here's a list of all my commands:", "\u200B", false);

// add an array of properties in this specific order
for (let item of array) {
    helpEmbedMsg.addField(item, "text here", true);
}

// add the rest    
helpEmbedMsg.addField("\u200B", "\u200B", false)
    .addField(`Type \`${prefix}help <command>\` to learn more about a command and it's usage!   `, `Example: \`${prefix}help ping\``, false)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter(`Command triggered in ${message.channel.guild}`);
```